# How to query location every 15 mins?

Tags: questdb

I have a QuestDB table with item locations similar to the taxi trip database on the QuestDB Live demo and I want to query location but no more than every X mins per item. Similar query on the [demo server](https://demo.questdb.io) would be

```
SELECT vendor_id, pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude 
FROM trips 
WHERE vendor_id = 'VTS' 
SAMPLE BY 15m
```

but get back error

`at least one aggregation function must be present in 'select' clause`

I don't want any aggregation like average etc, I just need the location every hour (or X mins). Is there a way to query that?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand well what you are trying to achieve from your description. 
Do you mean you want just the last 15min?

SAMPLE BY is an aggregation function - hence the message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `first` for aggregation

```
SELECT vendor_id, first(pickup_latitude) lat, first(pickup_longitude) Lon
FROM trips 
WHERE vendor_id = 'VTS' 
SAMPLE BY 15m
```